# Search engine for WP as CMS

Tags: search

I am running WP as a CMS at the moment and I've been looking for a decent search engine plugin to index the site. The requirements are:

- Facet posts based on custom taxonomies (aka, be able to drill down based on taxonomies assigned to posts)
- Fast
- Does not display the actual post but rather an excerpt

Nice to haves:
- Display most recent comment date, author

I have come across the Apache SOLR plugin and it does a decent job except for faceting by custom taxonomy. It facets by Categories, Tags, and Author but the Categories is so convoluted that I might as well rethink how I apply categories to the posts.

Does anyone have any experience with this? Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [SOLR: facet custom taxonomies?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/39376/solr-facet-custom-taxonomies)

Comment: I'll edit this shortly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1<sup>st</sup> You're looking for a search result display, not for a search engine.

2<sup>nd</sup> It's as easy as modifying [the Search Results Template](http://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_a_Search_Page#Preserving_Search_Page_Results_and_Pagination).

**Excerpt** can be used like normal in your templates loop.

**Fast**, depends highly on your themes code and the plugins you use, as well as your server, so I skip this point.

**Facet** Without a link to the plugin, it's hard to tell. A live example would be good as well.